# Phantom column appearing when returning SQL arrays to divs

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, count

I'm just beginning with PHP and mySQL (about 4 days in now) and have been trying to find a fix to this problem...

I have a set of items that I am returning from a mySQL database. I have these flowing into a set of 4 "ul" columns with a class of "models" with it dividing the number of results by 4 and returning "li"s and cannot figure out why I have a phantom empty "ul" at the end. I have tried putting the "ul"s into a foreach statement but that didn't return the desired results either.

Thanks for any help.

Here is the php:

```
<grid>
  <ul class="models">
    <?php

    $c = count($model);

    $s = ($c / 4); // change 4 to the number of columns you want to have.

    $i=1;

    foreach ($model as $models): ?>
      <li>
        <a href="model/?id=<?php htmlout($models['sn']); ?>" class="id<?php htmlout($models['sn']); ?>">
          <div class="<?php htmlout($models['callout']); ?>"></div>
          <div id="description">
             <h2><?php htmlout($models['firstname']); ?> <?php htmlout($models['lastname']); ?>
             </h2>
             <h3><span class="number">40</span> photo sets</h3>
             <h3><span class="number">756</span> images</h3>
             <p><?php htmlout($models['rightstext_left']); ?>
                <?php htmlout($models['firstname']); ?>
                <?php htmlout($models['rightstext_right']); ?>
             </p>
          </div>
       </a>
    </li>
    <?php if($i != 0 && $i % $s == 0)
    {
        ?>
  </ul>
  <ul class="models">
    <?php
    }
    $i++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</grid>
```

The HTML

```
<grid>    
**excluded**
<ul class="models">
<li>
   <a href="model/?id=AZWW5RJE" class="idAZWW5RJE">
   <div class="exclusive"></div>
   <div id="description">
      <h2>Model 19</h2>
      <h3><span class="number">1</span> attribute</h3>
      <h3><span class="number">6</span> attributes</h3>
      <p>textleft name textright</p>
    </div>
   </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="model/?id=AZWW5RJE" class="idAZWW5RJE">
   <div class="exclusive"></div>
   <div id="description">
      <h2>Model 19</h2>
      <h3><span class="number">1</span> attribute</h3>
      <h3><span class="number">6</span> attributes</h3>
      <p>textleft name textright</p>
    </div>
   </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="model/?id=AZWW5RJE" class="idAZWW5RJE">
   <div class="exclusive"></div>
   <div id="description">
      <h2>Model 19</h2>
      <h3><span class="number">1</span> attribute</h3>
      <h3><span class="number">6</span> attributes</h3>
      <p>textleft name textright</p>
    </div>
   </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="model/?id=AZWW5RJE" class="idAZWW5RJE">
   <div class="exclusive"></div>
   <div id="description">
      <h2>Model 19</h2>
      <h3><span class="number">1</span> attribute</h3>
      <h3><span class="number">6</span> attributes</h3>
      <p>textleft name textright</p>
    </div>
   </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="model/?id=AZWW5RJE" class="idAZWW5RJE">
   <div class="exclusive"></div>
   <div id="description">
      <h2>Model 19</h2>
      <h3><span class="number">1</span> attribute</h3>
      <h3><span class="number">6</span> attributes</h3>
      <p>textleft name textright</p>
    </div>
   </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your logic a little bit. Since you work with modulo, it would make more sense to start with `$i = 0`

You want to be sure to have an integer when you're doing modulo operations, so try:

```
$s = ceil($c / 4);
```

Then use it in your `if` to test if you're at the end of a `<ul>` element, and make sure you don't create one on the last iteration:

```
<?php if ($i % $s == $s - 1 && $i != $c - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Mathieu,
That seems to have remedied the phantom UL but now I have 5 columns the first UL with three li and a 5th column has five. My hope is to get this into 4 columns and have them expand in height to accommodate new items into the DB

Comment: That's because I started with `$i = 0`. I edited my answer please let me know if works.

Comment: that fixed the uneven number of `LI` included in each `UL` but still left me with 5 `UL`s. I changed
    `$nbColumns = 4;`
to `$nbColumns = 5;` and that provided the correct visual results... but as soon as a record was added it broke again. So my theory is that the logic you were using is working to define rows instead of columns.

Comment: @JasonKeeven I'm sorry, I just realized I'm misleading you, because I didn't understand your problem at first. Let me think again about it.

Comment: here is a jsfiddle of what I am trying to accomplish. hover over different parts of the gray area. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LAqHT/1/)

Comment: That seemed to push all the `li`s into one `ul` and looking at this I'm at a loss for where I would set the number of columns.

Comment: @JasonKeeven Edited again. Try `$s = ceil($c / 4);` to force integer calculations.

Comment: @JasonKeeven No problem! Don't forget to accept my answer, read this if you don't know how to: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/191928)

Comment: @JasonKeeven And don't include the solution in your question, that's what accepting answer is for :)